# How do I convert to numeric an exponential stored as a char in R?

Tags: r

I have a file with numbers in scientific notation stored as 0.00684*10^0.0023. When I read the file with read.csv(), they are loaded as character strings, and trying to convert them with the as.numeric() function returns only NA.

`a = "0.00684*10^0.0023"`

`as.numeric(a)`

`NA`

Is there a way to force R to take on the variable as Scientific notation?

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few ways.  They use `a` from the question (also shown in the Note below) or `c(a, a)` to illustrate how to apply it to a vector.  No packages are used.

**1)** Use eval/parse:

```
eval(parse(text = a))
## [1] 0.00687632
```

or for a vector such as `c(a, a)`

```
sapply(c(a, a), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] 0.00687632 0.00687632
```

**2)** A different way is to split up the input and calculate it ourself.

```
with(read.table(text = sub("\\*10\\^", " ", c(a, a))), V1 * 10^V2)
## [1] 0.00687632 0.00687632
```

**3)** A third way is to convert to complex numbers and the combine the real and imaginary parts to get the result.

```
tmp <- type.convert(sub("\\*10\\^(.*)", "+\\1i", c(a, a)), as.is = TRUE)
Re(tmp) * 10^Im(tmp)
## [1] 0.00687632 0.00687632
```

**4)** Another way to split it up is:

```
as.numeric(sub("\\*.*", "", c(a, a))) * 
  10^as.numeric(sub(".*\\^", "", c(a, a)))
## [1] 0.00687632 0.00687632
```

**6)** We could use any of the above to define a custom class which can read in fields of the required form.  First we write out a test data file and then define a custom `num` class.  In `read.csv` use the `colClasses` argument to specify which class each column has.  Use NA for those columns where we want `read.csv` to determine the class automatically..

```
# generate test file
cat("a,b\n1,0.00684*10^0.0023\n", file = "tmpfile.csv")

setAs("character", "num",
 function(from) with(read.table(text = sub("\\*10\\^", " ", from)), V1 * 10^V2))

read.csv("tmpfile.csv", colClasses = c(NA, "num"))
##   a          b
## 1 1 0.00687632
```

With this definition we can also use `as` like this:

```
as(c(a, a), "num")
## [1] 0.00687632 0.00687632
```

### Note

```
a <- "0.00684*10^0.0023"
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

```
library(stringr)
a <- "0.00684*10^0.0023" # your input
b <- str_split(a, "\\*10\\^") # split the string by the operator
b <- as.numeric(b[[1]]) # transform the individual elements to numbers

c <- b[1]*10^(b[2]) # execute the wished operation with the obtained numbers
c # the result
```